# set option B selected on selecting option A in JQuery multi-select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had requirement like when u select option A automatically select option B, i searched for function to select a particular option but i did not found any, finally i wrote i think its helpful.

```
<select id="multiselectid" multiple>
    <option value='optionA'>Option A</option>
    <option value='optionB'>Option B</option>
    <option value='optionC'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

here is jquery code snippet.

```
$("#multiselectid").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'OptionA' && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        selectOptionB();
    }
});

function selectOptionB() {
    $("#multiselectid").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'OptionB' && !$(this).is(":checked")) {
            this.click();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is function `SelectOptions()`?

Comment: Thanks for verifying i made a change to code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#multiselectid").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='OptionA' && $(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#optionB").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change `SelectOptionB()` to:

```
function selectOptionB() {
    $("#multiselectid").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'OptionB' && !$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked",true);
        }
    });
}
```